# Problem with htaccess redirect (looping)

Tags: .htaccess

I worked to do this for 2 hours but finally I gave up.
I have 2 conditions:
1. If user request a php file redirect cms/index.php?request=$1
2. If user request something different from php (png,css,jpg) redirect cms/website/$1
First rule works but I couldn't apply second rule. When user request /cms/style.css, Apache redirect cms/website/style.css and again redirects cms/website/website/style.css and it loops.

My htaccess file is like that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*\.php) /cms/index.php?request=$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*\.!(php)) /cms/website/$1 [R,L]
```

Note: I'm not sure that last regex is true, or not. And it returns 500. error_log output is

```
"[Tue Aug 16 16:26:11 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."
```

Comment: Apache logs are  alot of trial and error so it's hard to be sure, but that second rule looks infinite - if it matches. All rules will be run again after a redirect (`[R]`) so `/cms/website/$1` would match the rule again, and forward again to `/cms/website/cms/website/$1` etc.

Comment: @robin, actually [RewriteLooping](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLooping) says if I use [R], it mustn't loop. However, it loops even if set this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)\.(.*)$ /cms/website/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (.*)\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)\.php /cms/index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks! it works, but i couldn't understand what the problem is. do you know why [R,L] didn't work in my old htaccess?

Comment: @burak emre No, my too have problem using [L] Flag!